# Problem with Uv editing , in edit mode shows correctly and on object mode , really different

Tags: 3d-view, blender-internal-render-engine

[image: i dont know why i cant upload more pictures than one on here but the problem is that it is restricted to that area, i have tried to mark seam on the bottom and top lip and didndt work and its just stretches everywhere , i have tried to desolve the edges at which the image stops , applied ,]

i dont know why i cant upload more pictures than one on here but the problem is that it is restricted to that area, i have tried to mark seam on the bottom and top lip and didndt work and its just stretches everywhere , i have tried to desolve the edges at which the image stops , applied all transforms as well

Comment: are you using any modifier on the can?

Comment: i have Subdivision modifier on it , can it be the fact that i haven't applied it to the can before doing the shading ?

Comment: the reason can be very specific, can you share the can file? https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: sorry its a bit messy

Comment: you should use "file"-> external data-> pack resources before saving the files so we have your images as well

Comment: okay @chris give me  minute

Comment: @chris is this okay now ?\

Answer (score 0):

i think the main problem, why UV Editor is having problems to make a good uv editing is because of your double edges. I have no idea how you made them, but if you select that edge loop here:

[image]

and press X and dissolve edges, you will see, it seems to be still there. If you check statistics, you will see: edge count goes down. So you have a lot of double edges there. If you clean up your topology, upload file again if the problem isn't solved.

Comment: thing is that comes from the fact i add the subdevision modifire , so if u see it without subdevision , that edge doesn't even exist, imma redo it from the begining , thank you for the help @chris